# Is there a kernel module that returns exactly what a simple 'ifconfig' does?

Tags: linux, kernel-module, network-interface

I'm writing a kernel module that needs information about the local machine's interfaces just like the ones retuned by a simple 'ifconfig' command, I've searched a lot for it, but couldn't find anything

Comment: Check the source code for ifconfig and see what it does (or check with strace) and then check the linux kernel sources for what the network drivers does when these syscalls are executed. For instance ioctl SIOCGIFHWADDR, SIOCGIFADDR and so on.

Comment: For instance, check net/core/dev.c The function __dev_get_by_name() there looks interesting. You can probably use that and get some info about the interface from the returned struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get all of that information through the `struct net_device` one way or another. 
As Albert Veli said, you can get this `struct net_device` pointer using `__dev_get_by_name()`.

If you tell us what information you need specifically we might even be able to point you to the correct fields.

Finding the MAC address is fairly simple:

```
struct net_device *dev = __dev_get_by_name("eth0");
dev->dev_addr; // is the MAC address
dev->stats.rx_dropped; // RX dropped packets. (stats has more statistics)
```

Finding the IP address is rather harder, but not impossible:

```
struct in_device *in_dev = rcu_dereference(dev->ip_ptr);
// in_dev has a list of IP addresses (because an interface can have multiple)
struct in_ifaddr *ifap;
for (ifap = in_dev->ifa_list; ifap != NULL;
         ifap = ifap->ifa_next) {
    ifap->ifa_address; // is the IPv4 address
}
```

(None of this was compile tested, so typos are possible.)

Comment: well, I'd like to get the interface's IP address , it's MAC,it's status, the number of errored packets and lost packets and is there any way to get the speed or bandwidth of the link on this interface?

Comment: @ Kristof Provost Do you mean `ifap = ifap->ifa_next` instead of  `ifap = ifa1->ifa_next`?

Answer (score 0):

See for example the `in6_dump_addrs` function in `net/ipv6/addrconf.c` for how to get at addresses. For link properties like link layer address, see `core/rtnetlink.c` instead. ifconfig and its ioctls are obsolete (on Linux), so better don't think in terms of that now-bug-ridden program.